# Why azure blockid is changed?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to upload a big tar.gz file into the Azure storage, due to the limitation from azure, I have to cut the gzip file into small part, and upload each of them.

For each of them, I need generate a blockid (encoded by base64), the problem is that the blockid is changed a little bit after it is pushed to "staging area (uncommitted status)".

Here is the way how I generate the block id (using base64 to encode random 7 digit chars):
  blockid=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | fold -w 7 | head -n 1 | base64)

The generated example as follows:

```
VHRkS29qZgo=
ZUxXS0trVwo=
Q2JHVnlnaQo=
Z3FncFZ5Wgo=
SkZhTVhJcgo=
Rk9QaWxkTgo=
```

Here is the way how I push the blob into the server:

```
  curl -X PUT -T $file -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" "https://hello.blob.core.windows.net/jenkins/myblob.tar.gz?comp=block&blockid=${blockid}=&sv=token"
```

After pushing the blocks into server, I can see the block id is changed as follows:

```
VHRkS29qgg==
ZUxXS0trwg==
Q2JHVnlnQg==
......
```

Is there any reason azure change my block id?

Br,

Tim

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code you’re using to generate the block id? Thanks.

Comment: Could your provide the screenshot about how you push to "staging area "? As far as I know, if you change the content of blob, the block id would also be changed. I have tested it on my side.

Comment: Hi, pls see my updated question, hopefully it is clear enough this time.

Comment: Assuming the CURL request you're making is similar to what you have included in the question (except changing the account name etc.), I believe you have a typo in there. If you notice you're actually adding an extra `=` after your block id here: `comp=block&blockid=${blockid}=&sv=token`. Could that be the reason? It should be `comp=block&blockid=${blockid}&sv=token`.

Comment: I suggest you have auto-increment-like block IDs ( block1, block2, block3, ...etc) no reason for random.